# React Class is Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

The react class `myComponent` is not rendering inside the element `example1`.

what I am able to get in console is

You are using the in-browser JSX transformer. Be sure to precompile your JSX for production - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx

code

```
    <script type="text/jsx">
            var myComponent = React.createClass({
              render: function() {
                return (
                    <h2>{this.props.name} wants to eat {this.props.food}</h2>
                );
              }
            });

React.render(
        <div>
            <myComponent food="fruits" name="Raj1"/>
            <myComponent food="Veggies" name="Raj2"/>
            <myComponent food="Chicken" name="Raj3"/>
            <myComponent food="Burger" name="Raj4"/>
        </div>, 
            document.getElementById('example1'));
    </script>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow.com - You're doing it wrong.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. You can edit your posts to improve it, so please place your code in code blocks into the original post (and not in the comments"

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly, that console log is just a warning for performance purposes. It is probably not the root of the issue.

Comment: @ Georgette Pincin Thanks for your reply. But I cant figure out whats the issue with rendering. If I use                                                      React.render(
   <h1>hello world</h1>, 
    document.getElementById('example1'));                       It works fine.

Comment: I have posted a possible answer, with a working fiddle. If this has answered your question, make sure to accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the up/down vote arrows to the left. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must capitalize your react classes

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
          return (
             <h2>{this.props.name} wants to eat {this.props.food}</h2>
        );
     }
 });
```

[working fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1k15feh9/1/)